# How to import a package from a blueprint?

Tags: python, flask, python-import, blueprint

Imagine a simple Flask project implemented using the Blueprint pattern.

```
app
+-blueprint_1
|  +-__init__.py
|  +-views.py
|
+-utils.py
```

Now, imagine I want to import `utils` in my `blueprint_1` views using the best practice here: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/structure/#modules

i.e., I'd like to simply do `import foo` rather than `from foo import too_lazy, to_type, bunch_of, names`

How can I do this style of imports in a Blueprint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not the right way, it means `from` is good intention:

```
#blueprint_1/views.py
...
try:
    import os
    os.chdir('..')
    import utils
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I missed the very obvious answer, but apparently I can do this:

```
# blueprint_1/views.py
from .. import utils
```